# Изучение WPF (Анимация кнопки при наведении курсора мышки)

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток, Хешкодовцы

В продолжение предыдущего моего вопроса по поводу анимации с использованием триггеров.

Хочется сделать анимацию цветом при наведении курсора мышки на кнопку.
Для этого разработал стиль, который должен применяться при наведении мышки на кнопку. Но тут появилось 2 проблемы:

- Как применить стиль к кнопки при срабатывании триггера? Что-то никак не получается.
- Если не использовать стиль, то происходит нечто странное: триггер срабатывает и фон кнопки красится в желтый цвет (ну так и задумано), но после этого практически сразу (менее чем через секунду) он заливается ярко-серым градиентом, как будто где-то перекрывается моя анимация еще какой-то. Как это можно отследить, кто перекрывает мои стили?..

Заранее спасибо за Вашу помощь.

---

**Update**

Ну вот и опять появилось время для самообучения. Попытался вспомнить, на чем остановился, еще нашел неплохую статью в [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb613545(v=vs.90).aspx), делаю аналогично, но другие стили, и на тригерах опять столкнулся с проблемой. То ли читаю криво, то ли в windows 7 как-то особенно получается.

В общем суть проблемы как было написано раньше осталась. Код XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="150">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="testBtn" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Skyblue">
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                                <ColorAnimation To="Red" Duration="0:0:0:5"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource testBtn}"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

А вот результат. Изначально окно с растянутой кнопкой:

[image]

После наведения курсора мышки:

[image]

Убрали курсор мышки:

[image]

Итого видим, что изначальный цвет соответствует задуманному, окончательный цвет должен был появиться при наведении курсора, однако в момент наведения курсора видим какие-то стили от семёрки. Ну и окончательный вариант соответствует ожиданию, так как не обрабатываем уход курсора.

В общем, где я проглядел что-то?

Comment: Подменять стиль не очень хорошо, ведь вместе со стилем вы уберёте и триггер. Дайте код вашего стиля, подумаем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите, в чём дело.

Стиль для `Button` определяется примерно так, как в этом примере: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx. Вы видите, что анимация на MouseOver реализована в переопределённом `ControlTemplate` через `VisualStateManager` (почитайте про него, полезная штука). Что происходит на самом деле:

- срабатывает ваш триггер и переключает `Background`
- срабатывает VisualStateManager, переходит в состояние `CommonStates.MouseOver`, и применяет поверх ваших изменений свои вычисленные значения (которые определены в `Template`, унаследованном от системного стиля.)

То есть так сделать не получится, т. к. два фрагмента кода «сражаются» за цвет фона.

Мораль отсюда такова: если уж меняете стиль контрола, перекрывайте его полностью. Или пользуйтесь выставленными наружу свойствами, это предусмотренные дизайном точки кастомизации.

Comment: Как все запутано :-) но вроде помогла, надо самому сделать такое и по каждому телу почитать... Спасибо.

Comment: @pincher1519: пожалуйста!